# Meld Installation Ubuntu 10.10 not working

Tags: 10.10, ppa

I tried `sudo apt-get install meld` , but it showing `unable to locate package meld`. I tried after updating also. Can somebody help me find out its PPA or some other way to install `meld`

Comment: Ubunut 10.10 "Maverick" has reached End-Of-Life, please choose 12.04.5 or 14.04 instead, in which [meld](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/meld) package is supported.

Comment: As of now, I can't upgrade the OS. Is there any way to get installed meld ??

Comment: it seems duplicate of [How to install software or upgrade from old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still want to use meld on 10.10,

Please try this package: http://launchpadlibrarian.net/55033915/meld_1.3.2-1ubuntu1_all.deb

It came from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/maverick/i386/meld/1.3.2-1ubuntu1

Or you could pick an older verion [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/maverick/i386/meld).

Comment: Is there any way like adding PPA to source and installing through command line...??

Comment: How about `wget` the file and `sudo dpkg -i meld_1.3.2-1ubuntu1_all.deb`

Answer (score 1):

- Yep, all old releases are in:

  http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/
- Better to modify your `/etc/apt/sources.list` to point to the new URL, example:

  ```
  deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick restricted multiverse universe main
  ```

  to:

  ```
  deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick restricted multiverse universe main
  ```

Reference: [How to Install Packages for End of Life Ubuntu Editions](http://pogidude.com/2013/how-to-install-packages-for-end-of-life-ubuntu-editions/)